# C++ -- How to prevent an object from being allocating on stack?

Tags: c++

you have a class A, where you set ctor to be private, so a client can't call

```
A a;
```

to create obj on stack.
But someday another developer adds a new ctor:

```
A(int)
```

and try to call "A a(1);" inside main(). So this will create a obj on stack. How do you prevent that?

Here is my solution but I don't know whether or not it makes sense.

Use private or protected destructor for the class A and provides a factory function to allocate the object and a function to release the resource (i.e. call destructor)

Thank you

Comment: Compile the library and only give the other developers libraries and hard-copy. Seriously, you're asking how to write code that prevents the code being modified? This is a team process issue and not a C++ or coding one.  It may be as simple as a comment, or as complex as you having the only record of the source control password tattooed on your heel, Achilles.

Comment: This is just a trick question and it may not have practical usage. -- thank you

Comment: I'm with Tony. Think about your question: what's to prevent them from just making the destructor public or even making the first constructor public?

Comment: If it's a trick question, then obfuscate the code so badly that no one can modify it.

Comment: Why do you even want to prevent that? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 6):

Make the destructor private/protected. Works on the stack of a instantiation context which is not a friend or member of the corresponding class.

Answer (score 2):

Once you are providing the user the source code, you are entrusting the user and allowing him to modify the code as per his requirements, but then you would not want him to change it, thats a conflict.